# Android端末のディスプレイ出力の取得

Tags: android

Android端末のディスプレイ出力を、PCに送信して遠隔操作するアプリを開発したいのですが、端末のディスプレイ出力を取得する方法がわかりません。

どなたか、方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/) のようなイメージでしょうか？

サンプル： https://github.com/ferranpons/android-cast-remote-display-sample